# PostgreSQL ON CONFLICT with multi-column unique constraint name

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I'm running into a behavior I don't understand when trying to do an `UPSERT` with PostgreSQL. The docs would seem to indicate that the *conflict target* of the `INSERT` statement can be either an index expression **or** a constraint name. However, when attempting to reference the constraint name, I get a "column ... does not exist" error.

My first attempt was to just create a `UNIQUE` index, which works fine with the constraint inference:

```
create table kv (key text, value text, extra text);
create unique index kv_key_value on kv(key, value);
insert into kv (key, value) values ('k1', 'v1');
-- this works:
insert into kv (key, value, extra) values ('k1', 'v1', 'e1')
  on conflict (key, value) do update set extra=excluded.extra;

-- this does not
insert into kv (key, value, extra) values ('k1', 'v1', 'e1')
  on conflict (kv_key_value) do update set extra=excluded.extra;
```

Describing the above table, I see the following under "Indexes:"

```
"kv_key_value" UNIQUE, btree (key, value)
```

My second try was to put the unique constraint explicitly in the create table:

```
create table kv (
  key text,
  value text,
  extra text,
  constraint kv_key_value unique(key, value));
```

Describing the above table, the output of "Indexes:" is slightly different ("UNIQUE CONSTRAINT" vs "UNIQUE" in previous example):

```
"kv_key_value" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (key, value)
```

However I am still unable to specify the constraint name as the conflict target:

```
insert into kv (key, value, extra) values ('k1', 'v1', 'e1')
  on conflict (kv_key_value) do update set extra=excluded.extra;
ERROR:  column "kv_key_value" does not exist
LINE 2:       on conflict (kv_key_value) do update set extra=exclude...
```

Am I misunderstanding something here? I totally get that I can use the equivalent expression and rely on constraint inference, but I'd like to know why the constraint name doesn't appear to work when the docs make it sound like it should?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You got the syntax wrong.

For a constraint, it should be:

```
INSERT INTO kv (key, value, extra)
   VALUES ('k1', 'v1', 'e1')
   ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT kv_key_value
      DO UPDATE SET extra = excluded.extra;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @gstackoverflow Use the other syntax, as documented.

Comment: I would like to add my 5 cents. There is a difference between (1) "UNIQUE CONSTRAINT" on the table, and (2) "UNIQUE INDEX" (especially when it is partial), at least for this subject. For (1) one can use `ON CONSTRAINT` clause, and it will work, for (2) - one has to use something like `ON CONFLICT (name, companyId) WHERE companyId IS NOT NULL` --- full (2)-index expression (see `index_expression` and `index_predicate` in [PG-docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html). Compressing all this information in the comment was difficult, and I'm not a genius :'(

Comment: @maxkoryukov Then perhaps you could write an answer.